# A difficult coend computation in a CCC

Tags: ct.category-theory

Fix four sets $A,B,C,D$ and consider the functor
$$
T : Set^{op}\times Set \to Set : (U,V)\mapsto [[V × [U × A , C] , B],D]
$$
I would like to compute the coend of $T$, i.e.
$$
\int^{W} 
[ [ W \times [W\times A,C],B ],D ]
$$
but there is basically no rule I can apply to reduce this further.

So I have to get my hands dirty into the coequalizer that defines $\int^W T(W,W)$; the action of $T$ on morphisms on both components (i.e. the two maps that need to be coequalized) is given by
$$\begin{align}
&\lambda(f , x).(λ t.x (λ {(u , g).t (u , g ∘ (f \times 1))})) \\\\
&\lambda(f , x).(λ t.x (λ {(u , g).t (f u , g)}))
\end{align}$$
(I understand this is sort of unreadable, but the definition is fixed by how $T$ is defined, it's just a matter of writing it down).

Now, a plausible candidate (or rather, the only cowedge I have been able to find for $T$) is given using the evaluation of the Cartesian closed structure: $\epsilon^\star : T U U → \hom([[A,C],B ],D) : λ t → x (λ {(u , g).t (λ z.g (u , z))})$

But now, I have no idea how to prove whether this cowedge is initial... any clue? Did someone meet a similar problem before? Is there any intuition behind this coend?

Some context: this is just the $n=1$ case of something I would like to prove by induction, finding a suitably concise form for the colimit
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0} \int^{W_0,\dots, W_n} \hom(A\times \vec W, C) \times \hom([\vec W,B],D)
$$ where $\vec W := W_0\times\dots\times W_n$. Clearly it is enough to evaluate every single integral and then sum the results. If $n=0$, no problem:
$$
\int^W \hom(A\times W,C)\times \hom([W,B],D) \cong \int^W \hom(W,[A,C])\times \hom([W,B],D)\cong \hom([[A,C],B],D)
$$
If $n=1$, some currying (and let me denote all homs as []) gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int^{W_0,W_1} [A,[W_0,[W_1,C]]]\times[[W_0,[W_1,B]],D] &\cong \int^{W_0,W_1} [W_0,[A,[W_1,C]]]\times[[W_0,[W_1,B]],D] \\\\
&\cong \int^{W_1}[[[A,[W_1,C]],[W_1,B]],D] \\\\
&\cong \int^{W_1}[[W_1\times[W_1,[A,C]],B],D] \\\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: One small simplification: It seems like once $U \times A \to C$ is curried into $U \to [A,C]$, nothing in the functor uses any of the specific structure of $[A,C]$, so the two parameters $A$, $C$ can presumably be combined into a single parameter representing $[A,C]$?  (And this also seems to work in the general version with $\vec W$.)

Comment: I agree, the specifics of another object K=[A, C], once everything is curried correctly, do not matter.

Comment: a typo: looks like the $B$ and $W$ got flipped in the $n=0$ case, flipping $B$ and $[A,C]$ in the result which should be $[[[A,C],B],D]$.

Comment: Another observation: the map you mention induced by the cowedge to $[[[A,C],B],D]$ has an evident section, given by the coend inclusion at 1, so that object is a retract of the coend. I guess they’re not isomorphic, but I can’t quite see it for sure either. A fine gnarly coend you’ve found…

Comment: I fixed the typo. And yes, $[[[A,C],B],D]$ is a retract of the coend I want, but if this was the coend it would mean that for $n=0$ and $n=1$ I obtain the same result, which looks suspicious to me.

Comment: The way I look at it is this: let $F$ be the endofunctor of Set defined by $F(X) = [[X, B], D]$. You're asking whether $F$ preserves the coend $\int^W W \times [W, K] = K$ for every set $K$. For example, when $B = D = 2$, you're asking whether the double powerset functor $PP$ preserves that coend. I don't see why it should.

Comment: It certainly does not preserve the coend in question, and the evaluation maps form the canonical map $\int^W F\to F(\int^W)$.